# Alignment of rotatebox by baseline

Tags: tables, alignment, rotating

When I try to use several ±90° `\rotatebox`es one below the other, they are misaligned due to ascenders and descenders causing different sizes of boxes, as demonstrated below. How can I align them correctly? One workaround is demonstrated in my answer below, but I’m sure there is a better way.

I need this for setting rotated labels with `bigdelim` in tables.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\rotatebox{90}{peon}

\rotatebox{90}{eon}

\rotatebox{90}{lion}

\rotatebox{-90}{peon}

\rotatebox{-90}{eon}

\rotatebox{-90}{lion}

\end{document}
```

[image: wrong alignment]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible solution is add `\strut` to `\rotatebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\rotatebox{90}{peon\strut}

\rotatebox{90}{eon\strut}

\rotatebox{90}{lion\strut}

\rotatebox{-90}{peon\strut}

\rotatebox{-90}{eon\strut}

\rotatebox{-90}{lion\strut}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I wasn’t aware of `\strut`. It seems to produce an unneeded amount of space, isn’t it? Put a short text at the beginning of the document; the `\rotatebox`s will not be aligned with it to the left, but will be further to the right.

Comment: I marked this answer as the accepted one, as it is more ‘high level’ (in terms of abstraction) than mine. If one prefers to avoid the extra margin, they are better served using the `\vphantom` solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround is to have `\vphantom`s which contain capital letters and letters with ascenders and descenders (say, `Aby`) within each `\rotatebox`. I’m quite sure there are more elegant solutions…

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\rotatebox{90}{\vphantom{Aby}peon}

\rotatebox{90}{\vphantom{Aby}eon}

\rotatebox{90}{\vphantom{Aby}lion}

\rotatebox{-90}{\vphantom{Aby}peon}

\rotatebox{-90}{\vphantom{Aby}eon}

\rotatebox{-90}{\vphantom{Aby}lion}

\end{document}
```

[image: right alignment]